# MFC Ribbon edit control needs double click to activate

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, message-queue, ribbon

I created a simple MFC ribbon app using the App Wizard. Then, I removed all the controls in the ribbon and added a simple button, and two edit boxes, and added event handlers for each.

The event handler for the button is a simple message loop as followed :

```
void CRibbon2Doc::OnButton(){
    MSG msg;
    while (1){
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And the message handlers for the two Edit Boxes are also simple as followed:

```
void CRibbon2Doc::OnEdit1(){
    OutputDebugString(_T("Box1"));
}


void CRibbon2Doc::OnEdit2(){
    OutputDebugString(_T("Box2"));
}
```

Here is my problem :

**Case : Button not clicked, i.e. my message loop not running**

In this case, when I click on an Edit Box, I immediately see the blinking cursor that lets me write inside the Edit box. No problem here.

**Case : Button clicked, i.e. my message loop is running**

In this case, when I click an Edit Box, I do not see a blinking cursor that will let me write inside the edit box. I need to double click for the blinking cursor to show up. This is a problem, I would like to avoid making the users double click inside a box just to activate it.

Can you please tell me what could be the reason, and how to make it such that I can obtain a blinking cursor inside the edit boxes on a single click in the case where my message loop is running in the background.

I am basically struggling with a real life problem, and this is a simplified version of the problem, and a lot is on the line, please help.

Comment: Why are you running a redundant message loop in the button handler in the first place?

Comment: @MarkRansom, I have an old piece of code that I am redoing UI for, the code does data acquisition, it basically allows my application to be responsive to user events while it constantly monitors whether new data has arrived inside a while loop

Comment: @user3670482: You almost certainly want to move that data monitoring into a secondary thread, and leave the UI thread to handling the UI without extra message loop hacks.

Comment: Have you considered putting the data polling into the `OnIdle` function? That would allow you to drop the second message loop.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, as per your suggestion, I moved my data monitoring into a new thread, and now the UI is responsive as one would like. Thanks for the suggestion, you saved me a ton of frustration.

Comment: @MarkRansom, sorry I am not familiar with the OnIdle API, it looks like a member function of the app class, my data monitoring was in the document class, so I decided to first try moving the data monitoring into a new thread as Jerry suggested, that worked so I did not attempt the OnIdle approach. Thank you for your input, however. I do appreciate it.

Comment: @user3670482: Oh cool--glad to hear it helped.